# Rotation between point cloud and 360 images using potree js

Tags: three.js, point-clouds, panoramas, 360-degrees, potree

I am developing a web app to visualize point cloud data and 360 images using [Potree](https://github.com/potree/potree/) which is based in [three js](https://threejs.org/). I am having the problem that when I plot the 360 images the view between the point cloud and the images is a not well aligned. I have the heading, pitch and roll data for my images as it shows in the screenshoot below.
[image]
Also, I attached images of the error in the alignment of my data.
[image]

I tried to change the parameters of my images to see if the data align better but it did not work. I am a little be stucked .

```
import * as THREE from "../../../libs/three.js/build/three.module.js";
import { EventDispatcher } from "../../EventDispatcher.js";
import {TextSprite} from "../../TextSprite.js";

let sg = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 8, 8);
let sgHigh = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 128, 128);

let sm = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({side: THREE.BackSide});
let smHovered = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({side: THREE.BackSide, color: 0xff0000});

let raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
let currentlyHovered = null;

let previousView = {
    controls: null,
    position: null,
    target: null,
};

class Image360{

    constructor(file, time, longitude, latitude, altitude, course, pitch, roll){
        this.file = file;
        this.time = time;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.altitude = altitude;
        this.course = course;
        this.pitch = pitch;
        this.roll = roll;
        this.mesh = null;
    }
};

export class Images360 extends EventDispatcher{

    constructor(viewer){
        super();

        this.viewer = viewer;

        this.selectingEnabled = true;

        this.images = [];
        this.node = new THREE.Object3D();

        this.sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sgHigh, sm);
        this.sphere.visible = false;
        this.sphere.scale.set(1000, 1000, 1000);
        this.node.add(this.sphere);
        this._visible = true;
        // this.node.add(label);

        this.focusedImage = null;

        let elUnfocus = document.createElement("input");
        elUnfocus.type = "button";
        elUnfocus.value = "unfocus";
        elUnfocus.style.position = "absolute";
        elUnfocus.style.right = "10px";
        elUnfocus.style.bottom = "10px";
        elUnfocus.style.zIndex = "10000";
        elUnfocus.style.fontSize = "2em";
        elUnfocus.addEventListener("click", () => this.unfocus());
        this.elUnfocus = elUnfocus;

        this.domRoot = viewer.renderer.domElement.parentElement;
        this.domRoot.appendChild(elUnfocus);
        this.elUnfocus.style.display = "none";

        viewer.addEventListener("update", () => {
            this.update(viewer);
        });
        viewer.inputHandler.addInputListener(this);

        this.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
            if(currentlyHovered && currentlyHovered.image360){
                this.focus(currentlyHovered.image360);
            }
        });
        
    };

    set visible(visible){
        if(this._visible === visible){
            return;
        }


        for(const image of this.images){
            image.mesh.visible = visible && (this.focusedImage == null);
        }

        this.sphere.visible = visible && (this.focusedImage != null);
        this._visible = visible;
        this.dispatchEvent({
            type: "visibility_changed",
            images: this,
        });
    }

    get visible(){
        return this._visible;
    }

    focus(image360){
        if(this.focusedImage !== null){
            this.unfocus();
        }

        previousView = {
            controls: this.viewer.controls,
            position: this.viewer.scene.view.position.clone(),
            target: viewer.scene.view.getPivot(),
        };

        this.viewer.setControls(this.viewer.orbitControls);
        this.viewer.orbitControls.doubleClockZoomEnabled = false;

        for(let image of this.images){
            image.mesh.visible = false;
        }

        this.selectingEnabled = false;

        this.sphere.visible = false;

        this.load(image360).then( () => {
            this.sphere.visible = true;
            this.sphere.material.map = image360.texture;
            this.sphere.material.needsUpdate = true;
        });

        { // orientation
            let {course, pitch, roll} = image360;
            this.sphere.rotation.set(
                THREE.Math.degToRad(+roll + 90),
                THREE.Math.degToRad(-pitch ),
                THREE.Math.degToRad(-course + 90),
                "ZYX"
            );
        }

        this.sphere.position.set(...image360.position);

        let target = new THREE.Vector3(...image360.position);
        let dir = target.clone().sub(viewer.scene.view.position).normalize();
        let move = dir.multiplyScalar(0.000001);
        let newCamPos = target.clone().sub(move);

        viewer.scene.view.setView(
            newCamPos, 
            target,
            500
        );

        this.focusedImage = image360;

        this.elUnfocus.style.display = "";
    }

    unfocus(){
        this.selectingEnabled = true;

        for(let image of this.images){
            image.mesh.visible = true;
        }

        let image = this.focusedImage;

        if(image === null){
            return;
        }


        this.sphere.material.map = null;
        this.sphere.material.needsUpdate = true;
        this.sphere.visible = false;

        let pos = viewer.scene.view.position;
        let target = viewer.scene.view.getPivot();
        let dir = target.clone().sub(pos).normalize();
        let move = dir.multiplyScalar(10);
        let newCamPos = target.clone().sub(move);

        viewer.orbitControls.doubleClockZoomEnabled = true;
        viewer.setControls(previousView.controls);

        viewer.scene.view.setView(
            previousView.position, 
            previousView.target,
            500
        );


        this.focusedImage = null;

        this.elUnfocus.style.display = "none";
    }

    load(image360){

        return new Promise(resolve => {
            let texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(image360.file, resolve);
            texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            texture.repeat.x = -1;

            image360.texture = texture;
        });

    }

    handleHovering(){
        let mouse = viewer.inputHandler.mouse;
        let camera = viewer.scene.getActiveCamera();
        let domElement = viewer.renderer.domElement;

        let ray = Potree.Utils.mouseToRay(mouse, camera, domElement.clientWidth, domElement.clientHeight);

        // let tStart = performance.now();
        raycaster.ray.copy(ray);
        let intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects(this.node.children);

        if(intersections.length === 0){
            // label.visible = false;

            return;
        }

        let intersection = intersections[0];
        currentlyHovered = intersection.object;
        currentlyHovered.material = smHovered;

        //label.visible = true;
        //label.setText(currentlyHovered.image360.file);
        //currentlyHovered.getWorldPosition(label.position);
    }

    update(){

        let {viewer} = this;

        if(currentlyHovered){
            currentlyHovered.material = sm;
            currentlyHovered = null;
        }

        if(this.selectingEnabled){
            this.handleHovering();
        }

    }

};


export class Images360Loader{

    static async load(url, viewer, params = {}){

        if(!params.transform){
            params.transform = {
                forward: a => a,
            };
        }
        
        let response = await fetch(`${url}/coordinates.txt`);
        let text = await response.text();

        let lines = text.split(/\r?\n/);
        let coordinateLines = lines.slice(1);

        let images360 = new Images360(viewer);

        for(let line of coordinateLines){

            if(line.trim().length === 0){
                continue;
            }

            let tokens = line.split(/\t/);

            let [filename, time, long, lat, alt, course, pitch, roll] = tokens;
            time = parseFloat(time);
            long = parseFloat(long);
            lat = parseFloat(lat);
            alt = parseFloat(alt);
            course = parseFloat(course);
            pitch = parseFloat(pitch);
            roll = parseFloat(roll);

            filename = filename.replace(/"/g, "");
            let file = `${url}/${filename}`;

            let image360 = new Image360(file, time, long, lat, alt, course, pitch, roll);

            let xy = params.transform.forward([long, lat]);
            let position = [...xy, alt];
            image360.position = position;

            images360.images.push(image360);
        }

        Images360Loader.createSceneNodes(images360, params.transform);

        return images360;

    }

    static createSceneNodes(images360, transform){

        for(let image360 of images360.images){
            let {longitude, latitude, altitude} = image360;
            let xy = transform.forward([longitude, latitude]);

            let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sg, sm);
            mesh.position.set(...xy, altitude);
            mesh.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
            mesh.material.transparent = true;
            mesh.material.opacity = 0.75;
            mesh.image360 = image360;

            { // orientation
                var {course, pitch, roll} = image360;
                mesh.rotation.set(
                    THREE.Math.degToRad(+roll + 90),
                    THREE.Math.degToRad(-pitch),
                    THREE.Math.degToRad(-course + 90),
                    "ZYX"
                );
            }

            images360.node.add(mesh);

            image360.mesh = mesh;
        }
    }

    

};
```

This is the code of the class that it is synchronizing the point cloud and the 360 images

Answer (score 0):

as long as it is a class then you need to rerun the app to apply new parameters

i think you need to check Proj4
Add this to your code :

```
proj4.defs("WGS84", "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs");
            proj4.defs("pointcloud", viewer.getProjection());
            let transform = proj4("WGS84", "pointcloud");
```